# migrate SOLR files

Tags: solr

How can I migrate SOLR files (indexed) from one server to another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just copy your `data` directory under the path, where you configured your **solr-Home** wherever you want. See [this](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Is_Lucene_index_database_platform_independent.3F), because it is a Lucene index. Or you can use the [solr backup tool](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrOperationsTools#backup).

Comment: Do I need to stop SOLR before copying or can I do it online?